# Proof that the Euler characteristic is additive

Tags: algebraic-topology, exact-sequence

I'm reading through a set of notes which assumes that the Euler characteristic is additive, but doesn't give a proof, so I would like to understand why this is.

Let $A_n$ be a finitely generated Abelian group, non-zero for $0<n<k$. Consider the long exact sequence

$ \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow B_n \rightarrow C_n \rightarrow A_{n-1} \rightarrow B_{n-1} \rightarrow C_{n-1} \rightarrow \cdots $

where $B_n$, $C_n$ defined similarly to $A_n$.

I know that the Euler characteristic of $A$ is given by $\chi(A) = \sum_0^k (-1)^n \text{rank}(A_n)$, with similar definitions for $B$ and $C$. I want to prove that $\chi(B) = \chi(A) + \chi(C)$.

The notes say that for an exact sequence

$0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow 0$

of finitely generated Abelian groups $X,Y,Z$, we have the result rank($Y$) $=$ rank($X$) +  rank($Z$), and that the additivity of the Euler characteristic follows from this fact, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint.** Decompose the exact sequence you start with with many short exact sequences, each one corresponding to the kernel and image of the maps in the first one.

For example, if $f:A\to B$ is a map, you can construct short exact sequences $$0\to\ker f\to A\to\operatorname{im}f\to0$$.

**Later.** The point of the hint was for you to use the observation provided by your notes themselves. $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}\def\im{\operatorname{im}}$Suppose that we have an exact complex $$0\xrightarrow{f_{-1}} X_0\xrightarrow{f_0} X_1\xrightarrow{f_1} X_2\xrightarrow{f_2}\cdots\xrightarrow{f_{n-1}} X_n\xrightarrow{f_n} 0$$ For each $i\in\{-1,\dots,n\}$ we have the map $f_i:X_i\to X_{i+1}$ (letting $X_{-1}=X_{n+1}=0$ for convenience) so we have a short exact sequence $$0\to\ker f_i\to X_i\to\im f_i\to 0$$ so, **assuming we know that the rank is additive in short exact sequences**, we have $$\rk X_i=\rk\ker f_i+\rk\im f_i.$$ Multiplying this by $(-1)^i$ and summing over $i$ we see then that $$\sum_{i=-1}^n(-1)^i\rk X_i=\sum_{i=-1}^n(-1)^i\rk\ker f_i+\sum_{i=-1}^n(-1)^i\rk\im f_i. \tag{1}$$ Now, the original exact sequence being exact, we have $\ker f_{i+1}\cong\im f_i$ for all $i$, so of course $\rk\ker f_{i+1}=\rk\im f_i$ for all $i$. Using this in the right hand side of (1) we easily see that in fact $$\sum_{i=-1}^n(-1)^i\rk X_i=0.$$
In your case, my $X_i$s are $A$s, $B$s and $C$s, so you just need to rename stuff

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not quite sure what sort of decomposition you mean though

Comment: Sorry, still not sure what to do! Should I use 3 different functions $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$ for the mappings from $A_n$, $B_n$ and $C_n$?

Comment: Rank nullity theorem

Comment: @squirrel, well, these are abelian groups.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Absolutely, though I think it's a common colloquial way to refer to the behavior of the free rank -- at worst, by analogy.

Comment: @squirrel how does rank-nullity apply here?

Comment: @user160684: You can write $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{im} f) +\operatorname{rank}(\ker f)$ at every stage $\cdots \to A \overset{f}{\to} \cdots$ of the long exact sequence. Then use exactness to replace $\ker f$ and $\operatorname{im} f$ in appropriate ways. There's a lot to play around with there. If I understand Mariano's hint, this is essentially what he is suggesting. I simply wrote "rank nullity" as a comment on your "what decomposition?" question.

Comment: @squirrel Thanks! But I tried using the rank-nullity theorem and then exactness, and I'm still not there yet! I get $\chi(A) + \chi(C) = \chi(B) + \text{some other stuff}$ and I don't know how to get rid of the remaining terms. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: @user160684: There shouldn't be any other stuff left over because the overall alternating sum of ranks in the sequence is zero. To see this, forget about $A_*$ vs $B_*$ vs $C_*$ and try writing your sequence as $\cdots \to A_k \overset{f_k}{\to} A_{k-1} \overset{f_{k-1}}{\to} A_{k-1} \to \cdots$. Then deduce $\operatorname{rank}(A_k)=\operatorname{rank}(\ker f_k)+\operatorname{rank}(\ker_{f_{k-1}})$. Take the the alternating sum over $k$. Keep in mind that you have zeroes on the ends of your sequence. In fact, you can always tack on more zeroes.

Comment: @squirrel Thanks a lot, I managed to prove it using this identity. Everything cancelled out and the ranks were zero at the ends of the sequence so those terms didn't matter.

Comment: Very clear, great solution thank you Mariano Suárez-Álvarez