# Euler characteristic, what is the precise relationship between $\chi(V)$, $\chi(V')$, and $\chi(V'')$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

For a graded vector space $V = \{V_n\}$ with $V_n = 0$ for all but finitely many $n$ and with all $V_n$ finite dimensional, define the Euler characteristic $\chi(V)$ to be $\sum (-1)^n \dim V_n$. Let $V'$, $V$, and $V''$ be such graded vector spaces and suppose there is a long exact sequence$$\dots \to V_n' \to V_n \to V_n'' \to V_{n-1}' \to \dots.$$I am curious, what is the precise relationship between $\chi(V)$, $\chi(V')$, and $\chi(V'')$?

Comment: Do you have a guess?  Can you think of an interesting example, say the homology of a pair of spaces or a Mayer–Vietoris sequence?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that if $0\to A_1\to A_2\to \dots \to A_n\to 0$ is an exact sequence, then $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \dim A_i=0$?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/850950) the same ideas work perfectly well.