# Exact sequence of finitely generated abelian groups and alternating sum of ranks equals zero

Tags: algebraic-topology, exact-sequence

From Rotman's **Algeraic Topology**:

If $0 \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_{n-1} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow A_1 \rightarrow A_0 \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of (finitely generated) abelian groups, then $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i \text{ rank }A_i = 0$.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to start this.  I've looked at induction on the number of Abelian groups (proven true for $n=0,1,2$), using the first isomorphism theorem, and extending the maximally independent subsets but I keep getting stuck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can split this guy as follows:

$0 \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_{n-1} \rightarrow A_{n-1}/A_n \rightarrow 0$ and 
$0 \rightarrow ker(A_{n-1} \rightarrow  A_{n-2}) \rightarrow A_{n-2} \rightarrow \cdots$. Do you see how to induct from this?

Comment: If needed, I can post my proof for short exact sequences ($n=3$). Then, the general case is proven here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850935/proof-that-the-euler-characteristic-is-additive, using the case $n=3$.

Comment: @Laz I understand your proof, but why must the groups be finitely generated?

Comment: The groups must be finitely generated because otherwise $rk A_i$ could be $\infty$ for some $i$, and the equation you want to prove would not make sense. Take a look at Chapter 1, Section 8 of Algebra 3rd Edition, by Serge Lang.